# Прерывание функции по timeout

Tags: python, многопоточность, python-2.7

Мне необходимо закрывать подключение, но, в связи с нестабильностью работы OPC-сервера, метод закрытия - "вешается".

Мне нужно некое либо прерывание, либо продолжение выполнение потока.

Посмотрел возможность реализовать при помощи `threading`, но закралось подозрение, что вызываемый поток не будет закрыт, пока не выполнится метод `run`.

Как изменить эту реализацию, чтоб не создать утечку памяти?

```
import threading
import OpenOPC

class Worker(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, func):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.daemon = True
        self.func = func


    def run(self):
        self.func.close()

def test():
    t = Worker(OpenOPC.connect('localhost'))
    t.start()
    t.join(5)
    return
```

Comment: переформулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы он не был «классическим опросником».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С учетом того что "убить" поток - не хорошо, потому решил просмотреть возможность закрытия соединения в отдельный процесс.

После ожидания необходимого времени, процесс просто уничтожается. Этот вариант мне подходит так как мне нет необходимости отслеживать, что будет происходить в этом процессе.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import OpenOPC


def break_con(conn):
    func = OpenOPC.open_client('localhost')
    proc = Process(target=func.close)
    proc.start()
    time.sleep(10)
    proc.terminate()
```

Comment: Чтобы не ждать 10 секунд, если процесс раньше завершился, можно `proc.join(10); if proc.is_alive(): proc.terminate()` использовать. Здесь `join()` может вернуться раньше 10 секунд.